# Modelling and simulation of H2+H2O media and saturated water separation from H2 in OpenModelica

Tags: model, simulation, modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to model a media with two phase water and hydrogen mixture in Open Modelica v1.21. Further tried finding a two phase or Gas liquid separator model in Modelica standard library 4.0.

With limited understanding of how OpenModelica works, I tried to develop a media model for humidified H2 based on moist air. Here I replaced the parameters/variables of air with H2 gas. Further tried finding a two phase or gas liquid separator model, but was unsuccessful. So my questions are,

1. The values of the modeled media seems incorrect, how to model such a media?
2. Are there readily available gas liquid separator models or can a simplified separator model be developed, if so any suggestions?

I would highly appreciate with any help! Thanks!

Comment: Reg. Question 1. Why do you think they are incorrect? Please provide examples / figures + code, Reg Question 2: you can take a look at the drum boiler model in Modelica.Fluid, besides there are several commercial libraries available.

Comment: 1. I do not want to paste the whole code but as mentioned the model is replicating moist air and I have replaced air with H2. To start the enthalpy values are incorrect. 2. I will take a look at drum boiler. I am looking for an opensource library.

Comment: please provide more information (graph, code, how are you calling the values etc.)  for the enthalpies otherwise I can't help you. what does at start mean?